# Can I save Different image Views in a Dictionary to get their key? in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift2

Well I am designing Roll the Dice game in swift. So I am having trouble that how to move the dice item to entire image views. So is it possible to store different UIImage Views in a dictionary or List to get their numbers to easily move item to destination?

May be It's a bit confusing summary but I want to know that how should I do. I am done with random numbers now I want to move the item on each roll.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have understood well the question so let me know in the comments.

If you want to show an image depending on the result of dice number you can:

**1. Set an array of image names**

```
let diceNumbers = ["ImageOne", "ImageTwo", "ImageThree", "ImageFour", "ImageFive", "ImageSix"]
```

**2. Get the image name from array and display it**

```
//result is from 1 to 6
let image = UIImage(named: diceNumber[result - 1])
imageView.image = image
```

Comment: I got dice numbers so now I want to move the items  of (RED,GREEN,BLUE,YELLOW) with each dice roll to different locations. Hope you got it what I want.